# Interface inheriting Type script

Tags: oop, typescript, inheritance

I just want to write a User module which has multiple classes i.e. UserDetail,UserResestPassword so on .

There are some common properties which these classes are going to share , one approach I can declare property on every class and Initialize it.

The second approach is I will use of inheritance this will need to declare in 
interface

```
export interface Iuser {
    UserID:string;
    UserName:string
}
```

and implement it into classes

```
 import {Iuser} from './IuserDetail'

 class UserInfo  implements Iuser {}
```

My question is, is't supported in typescript? if not what are the way around to sort out this

Comment: What isn't supported? If you want inheritance use classes and `extends` keyword.

Comment: @Saravana I am getting following error


has no exported member 'UserInfo'. and following my extended class

            export class UserInfo  extends Iuser{}

Comment: Please update your question with a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript there is a feature called "type erasure" where all of the type information is removed during compilation so the JavaScript output contains no type annotations, interfaces, or ambient declarations - only real code.

This means that when you ask your module loader (at runtime) to get you the `Iuser` interface, it doesn't exist in the JavaScript file.

My recommendation would probably be to put your interfaces in files with their primary implementation. That means you don't end up attempting to load a module that is just a blank file.

For example:

```
export interface Iuser {
    UserID:string;
    USerName:string

}

export class UserInfo  implements Iuser {
}
```

And in other files you can:

```
import * as User from './UserInfo'

export class Example implements User.Iuser {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20i-user.ts%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0A%20*%20Interfaces%20don't%20actually%20exist%20after%20compilation%20but%0D%0A%20*%20%20are%20strictly%20used%20for%20type%20checking.%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IUser%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UserID%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UserName%3Astring%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20----%0D%0A%2F%2F%20user-info.ts%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20UserInfo%20implements%20IUser%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Just%20like%20interfaces%20in%20other%20languages%20you%20have%20to%20implement%20all%20members%20of%20an%20interface.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20TypeScript%20will%20let%20you%20know%20if%20you%20are%20missing%20any.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UserID%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UserName%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OtherInfo%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20---%0D%0A%2F%2F%20specific-user-info.ts%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SpecificUserInfo%20extends%20UserInfo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Methods%20from%20UserInfo%20are%20inherited%20and%20available%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20logInfo()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.UserID%2C%20this.UserName)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A):

Interfaces don't actually exist after compilation but are strictly used for type checking.

```
// i-user.ts

export interface IUser {
    UserID:string;
    UserName:string
}
```

Just like interfaces in other languages you have to implement all members of an interface. TypeScript will check if you are missing any.

```
// user-info.ts

import { IUser } from './i-user'

export class UserInfo implements IUser {
    UserID:string;
    UserName:string;
    OtherInfo:string;
}
```

Using `extend` all parent methods will be available and you don't need to implement them again.

```
// specific-user-info.ts

import { UserInfo } from './user-info'

class SpecificUserInfo extends UserInfo {
    logInfo() {
        console.log(this.UserID, this.UserName);
    }
}
```